# Visual Basic Interface and C++ DLL

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

Is it a good idea to use c++ for creating DLL files and Visual basic for the windows forms? It's like Visual Basic manages all inputs and the interface while c++ takes care of all computation. Is there a big difference from creating those with Visual Basic only?

Comment: It is not a bad idea.  Whether you are truly ahead depends a great deal on the specific code.  You'll be ahead a great deal if the "computations" involve floating point math on large arrays.  You'll lose if the cost of marshaling the data between the vb.net and the c++ code is high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a good solution to perform fast in memory operations with C++ and then use the results in .NET, we did it for an application in my previous company and it worked really well.

To make it easier to use the C++, we created a C++/CLI project wrapping the native C++ classes so we could just reference the C++/CLI project from VB.NET.